# Buffering an ellipse on a points layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, buffer, ellipse

I have a layer with a couple of thousand points in it. I need to overlay an ellipse (740m * 1100m) over each point. Is there anyway to do this quickly opposed to manually placing ellipses over each point?

Comment: Asking for solutions in two environments is effectively asking two questions. It is of course possible in ArcGIS Pro, but you already have two QGIS answers, so it appears you should [Edit] this Question to focus on that platform.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use "[Rectangles, Ovals, Diamonds](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#rectangles-ovals-diamonds-variable)" tool in the "QGIS's Toolbox <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> > Vector geometry". You can make ellipses by specifying the "Height" and "Width". Choose big value for the "Segments".

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use QGIS expressions [with Geometry generator or Geometry by expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814) to create ellipses. Use this expression on your point layer:

`make_ellipse($geometry, 5, 9, 45)`

The numerical values (`5`, `9` and `45`) are length of `semi_major_axis`, `semi_minor_axis` and `azimuth` (angle clockwise from north), you can change these values.

Optionally, you can even add another argument for the number of segments: the more segments you set, the smoother your ellipses will get.

[See also the help](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#make-ellipse).

*Screenshot: ellipse with axis length 15.000 and 22.000 and azimuth of 50:*
[image]

*If you use randomly created values, you get ellipses of different shapes and sizes:*
[image]